# Ajax return '0 in response data in wordpress, die() not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I want to remove '0' from data responce, here die() or wp_die() or wp_die('0') does not work.

in my ajax function i put die() but does not support.

```
function custom_coupon_check(){

     $output = ' <div class="iump-subscription-page-top">
    <form class="wrap" id="post_form" method = "POST">
       <input type="text" name="coupon" id="ihc_couponss" value=""/>
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom_coupon_check">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.__('Apply Coupon').'" />
       </form>
       <div class="ppl"></div>';

       if( isset($_POST['coupon']) ){
        if( $coupon = esc_attr($_POST['coupon']) ) {
             global $wpdb;
             $applied = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id,code,settings,submited_coupons_count,status FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ihc_coupons    WHERE code=%s ;", $coupon));
             // $data =  $wpdb->get_row($applied);
            // echo "hello ". $applied." coupon";
         } else {
            $coupon = false;
        }
         $coupon = esc_attr($_POST['coupon']);

        $success = sprintf( __('Coupon "%s" Applied successfully.'), $coupon );
        $error   = __("This Coupon can't be applied");
        $message = ($applied == '1') ? '<label class="coupnsucs">'.$success.'</label>' : '<label class="coupnerr">'.$error.'</label>';
        $outcome = isset($coupon) ? '<p class="cpresult">'.$message.'</p>' : '';
        echo  $outcome;
      }

return  $output;
die();
}
```

```
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_coupon_check', 'custom_coupon_check');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_coupon_check', 'custom_coupon_check');
```

Comment: Share your ajax function

Comment: please share your full function of ajax reply and action for ajax_nopriv .

Comment: @Dhruv please check, I update it.

Comment: @AliQorbani please check

Comment: It works fine now as I saperate the html form code output. and then put die();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will work for you

```
echo $output;
wp_die();
```

Comment: yes, echo $output remove other sections, it shows only the output part to the whole screen.

Comment: this is my output in ajax Response : This Coupon can't be applied

0